# just can't make clearInterval() works

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I've read through all post related to clearInterval, but somehow just can't make it work...
What the script does is the interval will be set once the ".xmas-title" change the image.
And the interval will be cleared once the mouse click.

```
var animation;
$(".xmas-title").delay(4000).fadeIn(400, function(){
    bear_shake(true);
});

$(".xmas-more").delay(4200).fadeIn(400, function(){
    $('.bg-xmas').css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
    $(".bg-xmas").click(function(){
        show_msg();
        bear_shake(false);
    });
});

function bear_shake(bool){
    if(bool){
        animation = setInterval(function(){
            $(".xmas-bear").delay(200).fadeOut(0, function(){
                $(".xmas-bear").children("img").attr('src', 'images/xmas/xmas-bear_o1.png');
            }).fadeIn(0);
            $(".xmas-bear").delay(200).fadeOut(0, function(){
                $(".xmas-bear").children("img").attr('src', 'images/xmas/xmas-bear_o2.png');
            }).fadeIn(0);
        },0);
        console.log('true');
    }else{
        clearInterval(animation);
        console.log('false');
        $(".xmas-bear").children("img").attr('src', 'images/xmas/xmas-bear.png');
    }
}
```

Comment: what seems to be the problem? why do you set interval to zero?

Comment: @akonsu bear_shake(true) will make the image bear keep changing (it will looks like keep shaking hand), and i want it to stop the animation when bear_shake(false), which change back to "xmas-bear.png", but it will change back to "xmas-bear.png" then continue the animation

Comment: do you mean that when you click, animation does not stop? notice that in the timeout handler you have animations too, which once they are started play to the end no matter whether you clear your interval or not. you need to stop them to stop all animations.

Comment: It's really bad idea to use setInterval for that kind a thing.and you are running the code really alot of times in a sec which is something your PC cant handle without processing delay.set your interval something like 100ms then it should work

Comment: The whole using setTimeout and delays is just asking for the trouble. By choice. Get rid of the delays and just fire the interval at the delay time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys, it seems I miss the basic thing and just tried to make things difficult on my own.
I've combine all you guys' opinions, and get it works now.
function bear_shake rewrite as below:

```
function bear_shake(bool){
    if(bool){
        var i = 2;
        animation = setInterval(function(){
            if(i % 2== 0){
                $(".xmas-bear").children("img").attr('src', 'images/xmas/xmas-bear_o1.png');
            }else{
                $(".xmas-bear").children("img").attr('src', 'images/xmas/xmas-bear_o2.png');
            }
            i++;
        },200);
    }else{
        clearInterval(animation);
        $(".xmas-bear").children("img").attr('src', 'images/xmas/xmas-bear.png');
    }
}
```

it now looks clear and simple for me, thank you all.
and I'm wondering is there any other better or smarter way to do this?

Comment: Asking Questions or giving answers ,  did not get you?

Comment: @surajrawat was asking the question, and found the answer after I get some feedback from other guys from the comments. Of course I still accept other better solution (that's why I didn't accept my own answer yet). It seems the code still can be more smarter, and I wish to see any other possibilities.